# Bitwise operation for UART, AVR

Tags: microcontroller, avr, c, uart

I'm trying to work on UART for AVR. After setting the baud rate registers UBRRnX, I'm trying to configure the UCSRnA register. 
[image: UCSR0A register.]

I'm trying to set the 2nd bit, U2XO. Which is the right way to do it?
`UCSR0A = (1 << U2X0)`

or

`UCSR0A = UCSR0A | (1 << U2X0)` (*Notice the OR operator in the 2nd statement*)

Answer (score 7):

In this case:

```
UCSR0A = (1 << U2X0);
```

`1<<U2XO = 00000010`, **1** is shifted to left to U2XO position so when you give this value to UCSR0A the register's content will be:

```
UCSR0A = 00000010
```

This operation will set all bits to **0** but the U2X0, for example if RXC0 would have been set to **1**, then this operation would clear it to **0**. If you are not aware of this that could cause some headache later.

---

In this one:

```
UCSR0A = UCSR0A | (1 << U2X0);
```

which is equal to this:

```
UCSR0A |= (1<<U2X0);
```

Here you set only the second bit to one and leave the rest unchanged which is preferable, because you won't change something accidentally. The content will be:

```
// UCSRA0 = xxxxxxxx               before operation something is in the register
UCSR0A = UCSR0A | (1 << U2X0);     // OR current with 00000010
// UCSRA0 = xxxxxx1x               something OR 1 will be 1
```

where `x` is the unchanged/previous value of the bit. If `x` is **1, 1 OR 0** will remain **1** and if `x` is **0, 0 OR 0** will remain **0**.

---

So I suggest the second way, because that way it is easier to track which bit is set and which not and you won't change previously applied configuration by mistake.

Comment: Thanks! Now I get it. I didn't know the 1st case would clear all the other bits in the register.

Comment: Yes, it would because you just make it equal to that value which has only one bit set, the second (U2X0).

Comment: Note that while this is true *in general*, there are some exceptions. Interrupt flags, for instance, will clear when they are set to 1, so performing a bitwise OR is some cases can clear other flags if a read-modify-write instead of a bit set is emitted by the compiler. They *must* be cleared by strict assignment to the register if not being handled by a ISR.

Comment: @Ignacio Thanks for the important addition, I will clarify my answer.And register description is always a mandatory reading before modifying any bits in the register, so these details will be revealed.