# Atmel studio coding

Tags: c, programming, atmel-studio

I am new to atmel studio, and want to know the best way to code this example:
What is the difference between using:

> ```
> DDRG |= (1<<DDRG3)
> ```

vs

> ```
> DDRG3 = 1
> ```

---

**Edit**: In subsequent comments, the OP changed his question to be:

"i could modify the question to . what's best `DDRG |= (1<<DDRG3)` OR `DDRG = 0x08`"

Comment: Where did you see the second syntax used?

Comment: lots and lots on internet , look at this
https://electrosome.com/blinking-led-atmega32-avr-microcontroller/

Comment: I see assignment as I expect it. I don't see assignment to arbitrary identifiers as your second example shows.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams
shifting from pic to atmel is a big matter . 
but i've to do

Comment: Nevertheless, there isn't anything like the second syntax under the provided link.

Comment: yes . that's what i was missing . 
atmel studio doesn't use SBIT

Comment: So actually your question is: "What does it mean `DDRG |= (1<<DDRG3)`, how does it work" ?

Comment: no . i ask about if there is advantage of using 'DDRG |= (1<<DDRG3) ' and not 'DDRG3 = 1' .
but after knowing that atmel studio doesn't use sbit ,i could modify the question to

Comment: no . i ask about if there is advantage of using 'DDRG |= (1<<DDRG3) ' and not 'DDRG3 = 1' .
but after knowing that atmel studio doesn't use sbit ,i could modify the question to . **what's best** 'DDRG |= (1<<DDRG3) ' OR  'DDRG = 0x08'

Comment: Check [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/183063/bitwise-operation-for-uart-avr/183066#183066).

Comment: Great link @BenceKaulics (+1) - I felt this question would have been answered before, and your link shows your good answer to a previous question. I would expect other good answers over at Stack Overflow too, since this is really a low-level C programming question. However to try to make it easy for the OP to answer his *specific* question, I tried to answer that (or at least, the new version of his question!). Anyone reading this topic, really should read your answer in your link too :-)

Answer (score 3):

Replying to your new version of the question:

> what's best `DDRG |= (1<<DDRG3)` OR `DDRG = 0x08`

There is no "best" because those two snippets<sup>1</sup> of C do different things - they only have the same end result in one situation; in all other situations they will have *different end results*! This means that, as always in programming, you must be *really clear* what you want to do and write your code accordingly.

<sup>1</sup><sub>[From now onwards, I will assume that they are followed by a semicolon and call those two pieces of code "C statements".]</sub>

a) `DDRG = 0x08;`

This clearly just sets bit 3 (the `DDRG3` bit, value 0x08) in the `DDRG` register.  Think about what values are set for the *other* bits in that register? They are all *set to zero*.

b) `DDRG |= (1<<DDRG3);`

This reads whatever value is currently set in the `DDRG` register, sets bit 3 (assuming `DDRG3 = 3`) and writes this result back to the `DDRG` register. Think about what values are set for the *other* bits in that register? They are all *unchanged from their previous values*.

<sub>[An optimising compiler, upon recognising that coding *idiom*, might be able to use a suitable assembly instruction, if one exists, to set that bit in the DDRG register - without needing to do the read-modify-write implied in the C source code - the end result is the same either way.]</sub>

---

So as you can now see, the *only* time that those two statements have the same end result, is when the other (used) bits in `DDRG` are *already set to zero* before each of those two statements were executed.

Using `DDRG |= (1<<DDRG3);` suggests to the reader (who might be you, trying to maintain the code some years later!) that you care about preserving the other bits set in that register. Note that using a bitwise-OR operator like this, is so common that it is used by Atmel in their ATmega128A datasheet regarding setting bits in GPIO registers, for example.

Whereas using `DDRG = 0x08;` suggests that you want to specifically clear any other bits which are set in that register, at the time when you set bit 3.

Which of those statements you should use, depends on *exactly* what result you want to achieve, for the value in the `DDRG` register.

---

<sub>I have used page 134 of this [Atmel ATmega128A datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-8151-8-bit-avr-atmega128a_datasheet.pdf) to confirm the DDRG register layout and DDRG3 bit value, 0x08, within that register. For other MCUs, the interpretation may be different.</sub>

Comment: In most AVR development environments, `DDRG3` is a constant defined as 3. (It's usually not a register at all.)

Comment: @duskwuff - thanks, yes, agreed `DDRG3` is a constant in the programming environment - it is also bit 3 in the `DDRG` register definition. I tried to be clear, but I knew that I could explain this several ways. I don't want a reader to think that `DDRG3` is only a constant, without realising that it is also a bit in the `DDRG` register!

Comment: Right, but the problem is, if `DDRG3` is a constant, the second line of code in the question is a syntax error, as it expands to `3 = 1`.

Comment: Yes *in the OP's original question*. However, note that he changed his question in a subsequent comment - *that* is the version of the question which I have answered, and that is why I prefixed my answer with "Replying to your new version of the question" and I quoted his new version of the question at the start of my answer. I will edit the "new version" into the question now...