# AVR. How to configure as output just one pin?

Tags: arduino, avr, c

In AVR C code, if you want to declare some port as ouput, you just have to to do this:

```
DDRB = 0xFF;
```

But how can I do if I want to declare as ouput just one pin. For example, I want to declare has output Arduino's pin 13, which corresponds to PB5.

I know I can declare that in binary format:

```
DDRB = b11111111;
```

But, I don't know which bit position corresponds to PB5.

Thanks in advance, I could not find this answer in Google.

Comment: "*...could not find this answer in Google.*"  Try the datasheet. Just set or clear the respective ddrx bits.

Comment: Set the fifth bit: `DDRB = b00100000;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PB**5** is the **6**th bit.
Just remember that the numbering is zero-based and starts with the least-significant-bit on the right, so the value you're looking for in this case is 0b00100000.
When you're setting this bit, you'll probably want to use a logical OR operation instead of a simple assignment, so:

```
DDRB |= 0b00100000;
```

instead of

```
DDRB = 0b00100000;
```

That way you won't inadvertently clear any of the other bits which might already be set.

Comment: The OR-assignment is particularly useful as it gets compiled down to one machine instruction, which only modifies that one bit.

Answer (score 2):

> But, I don't know which bit position corresponds to PB5.

You don't need to; the toolchain handles this for you.

```
DDRB |= _BV(PB5);
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is a register then there is a [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_Datasheet.pdf) that will tell you everything about the given register.

Description of DDRB register clearly shows that PB5 pin can be set to in or output by **bit 5**, which is the 6th bit.

[image]

If you want to set only this bit then the following [syntax](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/183063/bitwise-operation-for-uart-avr/183066#183066) can be used.

```
DDRB |= (1<<5); // 5 for bit 5
```

To make it more readable you can use the `PB5` macro which is just `#define PB5 5` (already defined under the hood).

```
DDRB |= (1<<PB5);
```

And to clear only the specific bit:

```
DDRB &= ~(1<<PB5);
```